# How to destroy folders in a custom generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, thor

I'm having a bit silly issue by creating my own generator in rails using Thor.

It turns out to be automatic that when you run your generator and it creates files in your code base, let's say

```
rails generate ab_tester test1
create  app/assets/javascripts/ab_test1
create  app/assets/javascripts/ab_test1/one_file.js
```

It's supposed that Thor is smart enough to know the inverse way when we call `destroy`

```
rails destroy ab_tester test1
remove  app/assets/javascripts/ab_test1/one_file.js
```

But as you can see, the folder that was generated to contain that file is not removed. I understand it's an expected behavior as you may want to keep some other files that were created later or something.

The question is: how can I ask/force thor to remove the folder when calling `destroy`?

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the Ruby way?

```
Dir.delete(directory)
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-delete

hope this helps